# How to add constraints to a view that has already been displayed?

Tags: autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I know how to add view constraints already but i dont know if the way im going about this is the correct way. So when my view first loads up i set constraints on views that are displayed when the view first loads up. I got to the updateConstraints method and add the constraints for the views that are loaded on the initial loading of the view. Now I have a few questions.

1) When the user presses a button a tableview will load displaying some items they can select.
When that button is pressed i call [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints] that calls the updateConstraints function in the view where i would add the new constraints for the view being loaded. In my updateConstraints method what im doing is checking if the view is alive by doing if(!myView) and then adding the constraints from there. My trouble i can forsee happening is that i also have all my other views wroking the same way. I check if the viwe is alive and then add the constraints if they are alive. But when i do it this way i have a number of if cases all asking if the view is alive then adding the constrints like so

[code]if(view1){ //add constraitnts for view one} if(view2){///add constraints for view2}} [/code]

and so on and so forth. Is this the corect way to add a subview after the view has already been displayed on screeen and the user is interacting with the application?

2) Will a UIView add constraints that have already been added. So say i add constraints for view1. If i write my code like the number 1 question it will again add the constraints for view1. Does this mean that ill have the same set of constraints twice or do i not have to worry about this?

3) If 2 is true and i have to worry about adding the same constraints twice whats the best way of removing them. Right now to remove them i have multiple NSLAyoutConstraint objects in my view class in order to remove them later once the view is removed. IS this the proper way of removeing conmstraints or can i do something else? If so what can i do?

Comment: So i answered number 2 the answer is yes. It keeps adding the same constraints over and over everytime i load up the tableviwe

Comment: I also just had an idea how about I can remove constraints for a subview without keeping the subviews constraints as a property of the view or viewcontroller , I can search the constraints of the superview. In each constraint there is a property callled first item. So i can say `if(constraint.firstItem == view1){[self.view removeConstraint:c]}`  Does that seem like a good solution?